# Is there a way to set alarm in android with local date and local time?

Tags: java, android, calendar, localdate, localtime

I am building a Calendar app to save events, show them and edit them with DatabaseHelper. I want to add alarm to these events but every I can find only setting alarm with Calendar import library. I want to set alarm in specific date and specific time.

Comment: I don’t know Android, so can’t tell. I would hope that this exists or will come. If all else fails, you can convert. Get a `Calendar` object from `GregorianCalendar.from(yourLocalDate.atTime(yourLocalTime).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()))`.

Comment: thank you my friend, your solution dont work.

Comment: [My code works fine.](https://ideone.com/5jfYlS) I don’t know what you did wring since it didn’t work for you.

Comment: I'll give it a try and I'll update with code reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am building a Calendar app to save events show them and edit them with DatabaseHelper. I want to add alarm to these events but every I can find only setting alarm with Calendar import library. I want to set alarm in specific date and specific time.

**Thanks to Ole V.V.**

**In this method i am creating a view for alert dialog, the function help me to convert date and time to start or cancel alarm:**

```
  public View setAllFields(View view,String id, String title, String comment, String date, String time, String alarm)
    {

        TextView id_lv_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.id_lv_tv);
        TextView title_lv_tv =  view.findViewById(R.id.title_lv_tv);
        TextView comment_lv_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.comment_lv_tv);
        TextView date_lv_tv =  view.findViewById(R.id.date_lv_tv);
        TextView time_lv_tv =  view.findViewById(R.id.time_lv_tv);
        ImageView alarmState = view.findViewById(R.id.alarmState);

        id_lv_tv.setText(id);
        title_lv_tv.setText(title);
        comment_lv_tv.setText(comment);
        date_lv_tv.setText(date);
        time_lv_tv.setText(time);
        Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from(LocalDate.parse(date).atTime(LocalTime.parse(time)).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));

        if (alarm.equals("false"))
        {
            alarmState.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm_off);
        }else if (alarm.equals("true"))
        {
            alarmState.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm_on);
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Alarm set problem.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        EventEdit ev = new EventEdit();

        alarmState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (alarm.equals("false"))
                {
                    startAlarm(c);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Alarm is set to: " + c.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    alarmState.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm_on);

                }else if (alarm.equals("true"))
                {
                    cancelAlarm(c);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Alarm cancelled from : " + c.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    alarmState.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm_off);


                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```